# NSFormatter for BOOL

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have set up my simple Xcode project with a table that is binded to an array controller.  It works fine if the array controller is full of entities with a string attribute.  However I want to change the attribute to a BOOL and have the table show the string "true" or "false" based on the BOOL.

I have overrided the following two methods from NSFormatter:

```
-(NSString*) stringForObjectValue:(id)object {
  //what is the object?
  NSLog(@"object is: %@", object);
  if(![object isKindOfClass: [ NSString class ] ] ) {
    return nil;
  }

  //i'm tired....just output hello in the table!!
  NSString *returnStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"hello"];
  return returnStr;
}

-(BOOL)getObjectValue: (id*)object forString:string errorDescription:(NSString**)error {
  if( object ) {
    return YES;
  }
  return NO;
}
```

So the table gets populated with "hello" if the attribute is a string however if I switch it to a boolean, then the table gets populated with lots of blank spaces.

I don't know if this helps but on the line where I'm outputting the object, it outputs __NSCFString if the attribute is a string and "Text Cell" if I switch the attribute to a boolean.  This is something else I don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it's not 100% clear what you're trying to do from the code, but first things first - BOOL is not an object, it's basically 0 or 1, so to place BOOL values into an array, you're probably best off using `NSNumber`:

```
NSNumber *boolValue = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
```

and placing these into your array.  Now you want to change your method:

```
-(NSString*) stringForObjectValue:(id)object {
   NSNumber *number = (NSNumber *)object;
   if ([number boolValue] == YES) 
       return @"true";
   else
       return @"false";
}
```

There's a few things here - for example, you want to avoid passing around `id` references if you can (if you know all your objects in the `NSArray` are `NSNumber`, you shouldn't need to).

Comment: I have a NSManagedObjectModel that has one entity and one attribute.  When I'm editing the .xcdatamodeld file I'm setting the attribute to boolean and initializing it to FALSE.  I assumed that the type boolean maps to the BOOL type.  Maybe I'm wrong on this one.  I tried the solution you suggested and it returns [number boolValue] however the table remains blank.  Maybe there's another method I need to override.